# Python: Counting frequency of pairs of elements in a list of lists

Tags: python, csv

Actually, I have a dataset about a "meeting". 
For example, A,B,C have a meeting, then the list would be [A,B,C].
Like this, each list would contain a list of members who participated in the meeting.
Therefore:

line1= (A,B,C)

line2= (A,C,D,E)

line3 = (D,F,G)

...

I just would like to count the number how many times each pair of members meet each other.
For example, member A meets C two times from line1 and line2 and member B meets C one time from line1. So, I would like to make a chart like this..

```
    A  B  C  D E F G...

 A  .  1  2  1 ...  

 B  1  . 1  0 

 C
```

...

I thought it would be easy at the first but I am pretty confused.
Please help me and thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Time to learn how to multiply matrices...

Answer (score 8):

Rather than manually summing frequencies, use [`collections.counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.counter) along with [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain, combinations

meets = Counter(chain.from_iterable(combinations(line, 2) for line in lines))
```

Where `lines` is an iterable of iterables of names.

Comment: +1 for using Python libraries. Everything's in there somewhere. >:P

Comment: +1 for a solution so blindingly self-apparent I'm kicking myself for not noticing it until your answer. When the other answer uses `defaultdict(int)` and does `d[item] += 1` a lot, that's kind of screaming out for a `Counter`. Not to mention the question being "I want to count ...".

Comment: Note that this will only work if the elements are in the same order in every list, e.g. `Counter(chain.from_iterable(combinations(x,2) for x in [[1,2],[2,1]]))` produces `Counter({(1, 2): 1, (2, 1): 1})`. If you want to count each pairing regardless of order, turn each list into a set first: `Counter(chain.from_iterable(combinations(x,2) for x in [set([1,2]),set([2,1])]))` produces `Counter({(1, 2): 2})`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple data-structure problem with a 2D array or dict. Arrays are more efficient if you have a lot of people, but I'll be assuming you don't.

```
times_met = defaultdict(int)
for line in lines:
     for pair in itertools.combinations(line, 2)
         times_met[pair] += 1

# How many times person a meets person b is described by the following (s.t. a < b)
print times_met[(a, b)]
```

Note that this is really inefficient if you have huge meetings and more efficient algorithms probably exist.

Comment: I think a dict of tuple -> int would make more sense - so that `people_met[(person1, person2)]` is the meetings between them. Then it doesn't need to be a `defaultdict` - just populate it initially from `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: @lvc A `defaultdict(int)` makes more sense semantically. If a new person joins the dataset, you can ask for how many times he's been in a meeting with anyone else and get the right answer - 0 - rather than a `KeyError`. Also initializing with zeros is pretty un-Pythonic. You never _need_ a `defaultdict` but it allows you to write better code.

Comment: The edit is good, but this is still inefficient for large datasets because you generate the cartesian product of the line with itself, instead of just the combinations. Remember that Python is batteries included -- there is already a way to do that.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the tip; I kind of misunderstood the first comment as that it would be best to use it to replace the initialization of defaultdict. This is much better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to solve this with matrix addition.  If you know the total number of people (G in the question), then your answer is going to be a GxG matrix.  Create a GxG matrix with the combinations from line1, then add in a GxG matrix with the combinations from line2, etc.